# How to select a random element by its index?

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

Lets say I have five elements in an android app with their own respective index

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']/android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='1']/android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']/android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='3']/android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='4']/android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']")).click();
```

And I only want to click **one** out of the five.
What command would I use to make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a random number between 0 and 4

```
Random r = new Random();
int result = r.nextInt(5);



driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+result+"']/android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number

```
Random rand = new Random(); 

int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

then assign this randomNumber to index.